# How to substitute environment value in JBoss naming subsystem

Tags: jboss, scripting, wildfly

I have configured my init.cli script like this:

```
set abc=sometext    
/subsystem=naming/binding=java\:global\/ABC:add(binding-type=object-factory, module=net.flexoptix.jbossTools, class=net.flexoptix.jbossTools.PropertiesFactory,\
    environment=[ABC=$abc])
```

The problem is that value ABC in the brackets is not substituted by value sometext.

I tried to find something useful but without success. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

I have found this post https://access.redhat.com/solutions/321513 (second method) but I am not sure if it's great solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the problem is the property substitution isn't being performed.  To enable this, you need to edit the jboss-cli.xml, in the bin directory, and change the following property to "true":

```
<resolve-parameter-values>true</resolve-parameter-values>
```

By default, this is false, and must be enabled when trying to use the --properties option for property substitution when running CLI scripts.

So I have changed the following code:

```
/subsystem=naming/binding=java\:global\/ABC:add(binding-type=object-factory, module=net.flexoptix.jbossTools, class=net.flexoptix.jbossTools.PropertiesFactory,\
environment=[ABC=${abc}])
```

And it works!

Comment: Just as a note this is done on purpose as a lot of attributes allow for expressions in the running container.